# Cómo puedo hacer que una imagen aparezca en un lugar y luego aparezca en otra ubicación, y luego en otra y así varias veces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Quiero que al presionar un botón se cree un comando para que desaparezca un png al cabo de unos segundos, y luego aparezca en otra ubicación, y luego en otra a los pocos segundos, y luego en otra, como si se estuviera moviendo. Traté de hacerlo con varias definiciones, con dormir y con el widget de destrucción, pero todavía aparece todo al mismo tiempo y no sé cómo corregirlo. Creo que se podría hacer con "for" pero todavía no sé cómo usarlo. Me ayudan porfavor?

```
def destroy_widget(widget):
    widget.destroy()
    
def texto():
    link=tk.StringVar()
    no=tk.Label(ventana,text="Hay algo en el camino...",font=("Times",18,"bold"),anchor='n',width=24, height=3,bg="#137420", fg="#9AD51A",bd=25,relief = "ridge")
    no.place(x=430,y = 400,anchor ='center')
    caja = tk.Entry(ventana,textvariable=link,width=50,state="readonly")
    caja.place(x=430,y = 410,anchor ='center')
    lin="https://www.tumblr.com/blog/mundo000011"
    link.set(lin)

def saliendo():
    canvas.delete(ima)
    ima2 = canvas.create_image(247,780,image=myimg)
    ventana.after(5000, destroy_widget, ima2)
    ima3 = canvas.create_image(247,500,image=myimg)
    ventana.after(5000, destroy_widget, ima3)
    texto()



def salir():

    if trad["text"]=="ar.ab.iz.":
        
        trad.config(text=leta)
        saliendo()

ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)

myimg = tk.PhotoImage(file='circlo.png')
posx=70
posy=235
ima = canvas.create_image(78,235,image=myimg)

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16), command=salir)
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=746,y=379)
```

Comment: Nose mucho de tk pero te ayudaremos, sabes como posicionar la ventana en un lugar en especifico?

Comment: un tk.tk? Bueno solo sé ponerlo así nomas como lo puseen el código :/

Comment: Haaa... bueno.... no podré ayudarte lo siento.